# Rate of change. Two ships sailing

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Two ships. Ship A is 25 km south of ship B at 8 AM. If ship A is sailing west at 16 km/h and ship B is sailing south at 20 km/h, question asks for rate of change of distance between this two when it's 8:30 AM.

The answer says 10.12 km/h, but I found 13.12 km/h. Here is what I've done.

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = 16 km/h$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = 20 km/h$$
$$t = 0,5 h$$
$$c = 25 km$$
$$\frac{dc}{dt}|_{t=0.5} = ? km/h$$

For $t = 0.5$:

$$x = 16/0.5 = 8 km$$
$$y = 20/0.5 = 10 km$$

Considering:

$$ x² + y² = c² $$

Derivative:

$$ 2x.\frac{dx}{dt} + 2y.\frac{dy}{dt} = 2c.\frac{dc}{dt} $$

Replacing values:

$$ 2.(8).16 + 2.(10).20 = 2.(25).\frac{dc}{dt} $$
$$ \frac{dc}{dt} = \frac{656}{50} = 13.12 km/h $$

Am I wrong?

Comment: Two things: What is the value of $c$ at 8.30? And what is the sign of $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}$ in the coordinate system you've picked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let ship $A$ be at point $(0,0)$ at 8am and ship $B$ at point $(0,25)$. Then at time $t$ (where $t$ is hours after 8am), ship $A$ is at point $(-16t,0)$ and ship $B$ is at point $(0,25-20t)$. The distance between $A$ and $B$ at time $t$ is therefore

$$\sqrt{256t^2+(25-20t)^2}$$

Now simplify this, differentiate it, and set $t=\frac12$ to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $y$ is the difference in latitude (north or south component of the distance between the ships), then you have been given that $y = 25$ at $t = 0$.  Since $\frac{dy}{dt} = 20$, I do not think it is correct to say that $y = 10$ at $t = 0.5$.

Your calculation of $x$ and $y$ appears to be based on the assumption that the two ships start from the same location ($x = y = 0$ at $t = 0$), which you know from the problem statement is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're wrong. The error is in substitution $c=25$ – this is the starting value at 8 o'clock, most probably **not** equal the actual distance at 8:30.